# Checks-Effects-Interactions Pattern - External Call not reached

Tags: contract-development

What happens if one uses Checks-Effects-Interactions Pattern and the gas runs out before the last line of the code in the contract can be reached, i.e., the last line is to interact with another contract and/or making an external call.

The resultant state is an incorrect state as the contract execution is incomplete. Would the use of revert() work?

What if the revert line is never reached as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to worry about that. If the transaction runs out of gas, it is reverted as a whole. That means, as far as your smart contract is concerned, it will be like the transaction never happened

Comment: Thanks. To see if i understand you correctly, it reverts the whole transaction call? Pretty similar to a 2 phase commit

Comment: Yes, the whole transaction is reverted